# Least performance hindering live graphing for python

Tags: python, plot, while-loop

## Edit:

I'm running a genetic algorithm and would like to plot the fitness of each generation as the algorithm progresses. At the moment my code works like this:

```
# INITIALIZATION - PLEASE NOTE: INCOMPLETE EXAMPLE
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax1.set_xlim([0, generations])
ax1.set_ylim([1000, 10000])
ax1.set_title('Creature fitness')
ax1.set_ylabel('Fitness')
ax1.set_xlabel('Generations')
xs = []
ys = []

line, = ax1.plot(xs, ys)

generation = 1
generations = 100

while generation < generations:

    # - some calculations here

    generation_fitness = x # from calculations above

    xs.append((generation))
    ys.append((generation_fitness))
    line.set_xdata(xs)
    line.set_ydata(ys)
    plt.pause(0.1)
```

However, this produces a very stuttering graph like so: [image: so]
and I think it slows down code execution.

I would like to have something like the "Wind speed" graph [here](https://dash-gallery.plotly.host/dash-wind-stream) but hopefully a lot less complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very specific but for these types of problems, generally, you should separate UI (the graph) and logic of the app into threads so they cannot interfere with each other.

You should start a separate thread to render the graph and use some thread-safe construct to pass the data from the logic thread to the rendering-thread. In this case you will probably need `queue.Queue` (Google it).